# JAVA регулярные выражения. Найти по шаблону слово и из этого слова извлечь "подслово"

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Здраствуйте. Надо в JAVA регулярным выражением найти по шаблону слово и из этого слова извлечь "подслово".
Пример:

```
    String str = "<person userID=\"001\">";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("userID=\"\\w*\""); 
    Matcher match = patt.matcher(str);
    if(match.find())
        System.out.printf("found: %s", match.group("(^userID=\")\\w*\""));
```

Находим строку ***userID="001"***. Можно ли выражением

```
match.group("(^userID=\")\\w*\"");
```

извлечь только ***001*** ? Если да, подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать? Или если есть какой-нибудь другой способ.

Comment: Оборачиваем в скобки ту часть, которая нам нужна, и используем соответствующий номер группы при поиске - `Pattern.compile("userID=\"(\\w*)\"")` > `match.group(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала определимся с методом `group()`. Он не может принимать в качестве аргумента регулярное выражение. Он предназначен для работы с захватываемыми группами, то есть на вход этому методу даётся либо номер либо имя группы.

Поэтому предлагаю завернуть нужное вам подслово в группу и затем извлечь его. Поскольку в этом примере одна группа, то и дополнительных аргументов методу передавать не нужно. :)

```
String str = "<person userID=\"001\">";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("userID=\"(\\w*)\"");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(str);
if (match.find()) {
    System.out.println(match.group(1));
}
```

//в методе match.group(1) нужно было указать номер группы, но всё равно спасибо за развёрнутый ответ )

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "<person userID=\"001\">";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("userID=(\"\\w*\")");
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(str);
    if (match.find()) System.out.printf("found: %s", match.group(1));
  }
```